# Error in LocalStorage using Parse in Swift iOs

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am new using parse. I have tried to Create a user object using parse user signup and then tried to save the User object to the local storage. Now when I try to retrieve that object, I the error that

```
[Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)
```

**The code where I signup the user is**

```
var user = PFUser()
            user.username = userNameTF.text
            user.password = passwordTF.text
            user.email = self.userProfile.userEmail
            // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
            user["gender"] = self.userProfile.userGender
            user["school"] = self.userSchoolName.text
            user["userFullName"] = self.userProfile.userFullName



            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                    var errorCode: String = error.valueForKey("code") as! String

                } else {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    println("Signup Successfull")
                    self.objectId = user.objectId!

                }
            }

        user.pinInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

            if(success == true){
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUpToProfile", sender: self)
            }
        }
```

**The code for retrieving the saved user object looks like this**

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
var queryResult =  query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("SO3LKyHtaa").continueWithBlock {
    (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject in
    if let error = task.error {
        // Something went wrong.
        println("Error fetching from DB")
        return task;
    }
    println(task.result.count)
    // task.result will be your game score
    return task;
}
```

The above code part, return me the error stated above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the query the `PFUser` id is hard coded to SO3LKyHtaa. How do you know that is the correct id?

Comment: self.objectId = user.objectId

Comment: Rather than hard coding the `PFUser` id, use `self.objectId`, e.g., var `queryResult =  query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.objectId).continueWithBlock {` The id will be different every time a new `PFUser` is created.

Comment: Also, just remembered, when using `PFUser`, you should prefix User with an underscore, e.g., `let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")`

Comment: Ok, I will try this and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I tried. I does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse automatically pins the signed in/logged in PFUser for you. Instead of doing that and pinning the userId do this. Do your sign up step normally.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                var errorCode: String = error.valueForKey("code") as! String

            } else {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                println("Signup Successfull")
                // Don't need to store the userId
                // Do your segue or whatever after sign up here.
            }
        }
```

Then to retrieve the user once he/she has logged in/signed up:

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()
{
     // user is now the current user object.
}
else 
{
     // User has not yet signed up or logged in show sign up/login page. 
}
```

Here is the Parse documentation about it: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/currentUser

Also when you want to log the user out so as to 'unpin' the user simply do this:

```
PFUser.logOutInBackground { // Logged out now. }
```

Comment: This is ok, my question is that will this be stored in the local storage, if I close the app and open again, Will I still get the user details with PFUser.currentUser() ?

Comment: Yes you will. But if you still don't trust that you can use PFUser.currentUser().fetchIfNeededInBackground { // code to execute after fetch }